# Is it possible to plug into maven artifact resolution

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Problem:

I work on a project that has a lot of dependencies. The dependency versions are being pinned using a complex pom file hierarchy.

For a dependency ( say A ) that is currently pinned to version V_a, I want to have maven instead use another version V_b of that dependency.

Is it possible to do this in maven using some sort of a plugin that inserts itself into the maven artifact resolution phase, and changes the version of the artifact from V_a to V_b ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want having an other version you can simply add this particular artifact with the different version to your pom which should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I know that will work. However that would mean that everyone on our team would have to make that change to their local POMs. I want to have something that will work with little or no effort.

Comment: From my understanding what you like to achieve it's not possible. The intention of versions (or better groupId, artifactId, version) is to identify an artifact. If you need to use a different version of an artifact you need to change the pom which describes which versions are used to create that artifact.

Comment: I thought there might be a way using artifactresolver or something similar.